# Github Pages does not display pages like local machine

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages, gemfile, gemfile.lock

I create a site with jekyll using the theme minima. The site displays everything well in my local machine(localhost:4000). But it appears strangely on Github Pages. It looks like [this](https://hljhnu.github.io/blog/).This is the [source](https://github.com/hljhnu/blog/tree/gh-pages) hosted on [github](https://www.github.com/). I tried to modify the files Gemfile and Gemfile.lock, but it remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

There is no post in your blog. No post no print with the [minima home template](https://github.com/jekyll/minima/blob/master/_layouts/home.html).

Add one post and the magic will append.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I figure out the cause. I left the variable `baseurl` as empty  in `_config.xml`. The page looks normal after I set `baseurl` to `/blog`.